# copy paste from another research (for figures)

Tags: plagiarism

I know that we should not copy paste any text from one research.
it is form of plagerisim.

but can I copy a figure/chart from one research and put it in mine (with mentioning the reference) ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can. It's the same as with all copyrighted material - you need permission from the copyright holder, you need to pay royalties, or you need to qualify for [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use).

Fair use has four general factors to think of:

- What are you using the figure for?
- What is the nature of the original work with the figure?
- How much of the original work are you copying?
- Does your duplicating the original work hurt the original's sales?

It's generally a tough topic - see the Wikipedia article for more details - but if you're taking a single figure out of another paper and using it in your paper with attribution, you are probably within the fair use regime and it's OK to use it without getting explicit permission from the copyright holder.

Comment: This is just for my PhD confirmation of candidature. I am just copying that figure from one research I found nothing else copied from anywhere

Comment: it is just illustrate the hierarichy of ICD9